# Check allusers everyday, Java on tomcat + Neo4j

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin, vaadin7

For a VAADIN Java Application running on Tomcat7 with Neo4j Database System, i need to create a routine that checks all users everyday at 12AM, and sends email to all of the users who have been returned by my request (the request is ready, and works well).

The problem is here:

I don't know how to start one of my class each day at 12 AM in the application, i already tried Quartz and Java.ejb.Schedule but none of them have worked, Quartz creates me a memory error and only starts the class once, and ajb is simply not working (no loop at all).

Is there an easier way to achieve this? i just need to start my class each day, even if no users are on the application.

Comment: Just as an idea. You could create a cronjob which will make a post to your server to trigger this event.

Comment: by using curl? it's a good idea ! I'll try it and see if it's the solution. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Yepp curl would be a possible solution.

Comment: quartz would be pretty standard in java world.  but without a proper error mesasge/code it would be hard to guess, what went wrong.  using curl with plain vaadin won't be that easy, as you would first have to provide an endpoint to trigger your task (no biggy if you also use spring-web or alike).

Comment: Quatz works fine with tomcat, we use it ouself in different tomcat deployments. But as mentioned before, a stacktrace and some code would be very helpfull.